# How do replace a specific part of a line using sed without replacing the rest of the line?

Tags: sed, terminal, regular-expression

Suppose I have the following file called `Product.java`:

```
public class Product {
    public String name;
    public String description;
    public String picture;
    public double price;

    public Product(String name, String description, String picture, double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.picture = picture;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    public String getPicture() {
        return this.picture;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return this.price;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Product";
    }
}
```

What I am currently trying to do is to replace instances of `public` with `private` for the class fields only in `Product.java`, updating the file in place. So, after replacement, the file should look like:

```
public class Product {
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String picture;
    private double price;
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

I tried doing this by using `sed` with the following statement:

```
sed -ri 's/public [a-zA-Z a-z]*;/private/' Product.java
```

However, this just replaces the class fields to just `private`. Due to this, I was wondering how do I just replace the `public` part of the lines with `private` while keeping the rest of the line unchanged? I'm unsure how to accomplish this behavior. Any feedback or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `sed -ri 's/public ([a-zA-Z a-z]*;)/private \1/' Product.java`

Comment: @Isaac Thank you. I didn't realize I could use `\1` to back reference. It is super helpful to know for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

ImHere already told you how to solve that very problem by referring to parts of the pattern in the replacement, but I'd like to add some useful hints:

- Don't use `-r` for extended regular expression syntax (btw, your original command didn't make use of it anyhow). `-E` is the portable option.
- Always think about whether all possible cases are covered. What about `public int[] foo` or `public String description2` or line breaks between `public` and `;`?
- Sometimes it better to exclude cases by an inverted *address* like `sed '/{/!s/public /private /'`which replaces all `public` unless there is a `{` on that line
- Finally think about false positives like a comment `// don't allow a public setter for this member; it can only be set on instanisation` or some (in this case stupid edge) case with a variable called `republic`, so your pattern should better be `^[[:space:]]*public`

Together, a more robust script could look like

```
sed '/{/!s/^\([[:space:]]*\)public /\1private /'
```